# FunctionPass in LLVM for C++ input

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-clang

I am trying to print all functions' names in my C/C++ code by parsing the code through LLVM. I referred the example given here http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#basic-code-required 
The example works fine for C code input but for C++ input, it displays following function names in a simple Hello World program

__cxx_global_var_init

main

*GLOBAL*_I_a

Then I found that LLVM has a certain issue with iostream as explained here: http://llvm.org/docs/FAQ.html#what-is-this-llvm-global-ctors-and-global-i-a-stuff-that-happens-when-i-include-iostream

I removed iostream from my code and then I got only "main" as output.

But for a multi-function C++ program that lets say contains the following functions: convertperm, findType and main (does not have iostream), I got the following output

_Z11convertpermSs

_Z8findtypeSs

main

Multi-function C programs work properly

Can anyone provide a fix to this problem?

Comment: Use `c++filt` tool to convert the mangled names. If you're interested in only printing declarations that came from your source files (not the included headers), use debug metadata.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of [C++ name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) :)

Your front-end (Clang, I'm assuming) has renamed these functions, a process called *mangling*. If you want to get the original function name back, you'll need to *demangle* the mangled names. You can read the linked article to learn more about why and how mangling and demangling are done.

As far as I know there's no built-in C++ demangler in LLVM, but you can use an external one, for instance [libstdc++'s `abi::__cxa_demangle`](http://panthema.net/2008/0901-stacktrace-demangled/cxa_demangle.html).

Comment: Is there any way to stop the compiler from doing mangling? My compiler is clang++.

Comment: @RohanBhalla yes, [use `extern "C"` around your functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c).